# Edit headers in Ag-grid

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

Ag-grid gives support to edit column cells. How do I edit column headers in ag-grid?

Answer (score 1):

It's there on documentations itself. Link: **[Updating Column Definitions](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-definitions/#changing-column-headers)**

> After the grid has been initialised it may be necessary to update the
>   column definition. It is important to understand that when a column is
>   created it is assigned a copy of the column definition defined in the
>   GridOptions. For this reason it is necessary to obtain the column
>   definition directly from the column.
>
> The following example shows how to update a column header name after
>   the grid has been initialised. As we want to update the header name
>   immediately we explicitly invoke refreshHeader() via the Grid API.
>
> ```
> // get a reference to the column
> var col = gridOptions.columnApi.getColumn("colId");
>
> // obtain the column definition from the column
> var colDef = col.getColDef();
>
> // update the header name
> colDef.headerName = "New Header";
>
> // the column is now updated. to reflect the header change, get the grid refresh the header
> gridOptions.api.refreshHeader();
> ```

Answer (score 0):

A. Set header before init:

```
var columnDefinition = [{headerName: 'yourHeaderName', field:'fieldNameFromDataSource'}]//define
gridOptions = {columnDefs: columnDefinition}
```

B. Change header after rendered:

```
var col = gridOptions.columnApi.getColumn('fieldName');
var colDef = col.getColDef();
colDef.headerName = 'newHeaderName';
gridOptions.api.refreshHeader();
```